# Counterexample for $f(h) = O(||h||)$ but $f(X_n) = O_p(X_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, statistics

This is problem 2.12.ii from Asymptotic Statistics (van der Vaart):

Give a function $f$ for which $f(h) = O(||h||)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ and a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n = O_p(1)$ but $f(X_n) \neq O_p(X_n)$.

**What I've tried**

Define $g(h) = f(h)/||h|| = O(1)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$, so there exists $M, \delta > 0$ such that $||h|| \leq \delta \implies g(h) \leq M$.

We need to find an $f$ and a sequence $X_n$ such that there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that there is no single $M>0$ for which: $P(|g(X_n)| \geq M) \leq \epsilon$ for all $n$.

From lemma 2.12 in vdV, $g(X_n) = O_p(1)$ if $f(0) = 0$ and $X_n = o_p(1)$, but I am having trouble coming up with a counterexample.

Comment: Since $X_n$ is only bounded in probability and is not supposed to go to zero, even in any sort of weak way, the assumption on $f$ is not very useful. Unless I am missing something, there is even a deterministic counterexample, e.g. $f(x) = x/(1-x)$ and $X_n = 1-1/n$. (Obviously this does not work if you want $f$ to be continuous on the real line, but as written this is not assumed, right?)

Comment: Oh that's right, the condition on $f$ specifies as $h \rightarrow 0$, so if $X_n$ does not tend to $0$ in probability, then the condition is not relevant. Thanks!

Comment: You can get proper double bars for norms using `\|` instead of `||`.